# Switching JPanels and keyListeners

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

I am developing a game, where you first get to the main screen, there are multiple selections to go, for example, Singleplayer, Twoplayer, Credits, etc.

I have one big problem. If I click a button in the menu, (not `JButton`) the `JPanel`s switch, but the keyListener is lost. The `Keylistener` is in the same class as the game code, which implements `JPanel`. I tried everything to get the `Keylistener` to work, but it just won't.

Here is how the things are called: Main class --> Menu --> Game. I tried adding the keylistener to the main class, but it's not working.

So, `JPanel` switching is ok, but the `Keylistener`s are gone. I was developing the game before with new `JFrame`s, so when I clicked a menu, a new frame was created. I didn't insert a code here, because it's too long (2000+ lines), and the `KeyListener` is working, but only when it is in a new `JFrame`. I set the mode int in the Menu class, by clicking a button.

This is currently my panel switch:

```
public void setJPanel() {
     switch (mode) {
        case 1:
            getContentPane().add(s);
            validate();
            break;
        case 2:
            getContentPane().removeAll();
            getContentPane().add(sp);
            validate();
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use a KeyListener, have you given thought to or tried using Key Bindings? KeyListeners require that the component being listened to has focus, and focus may be lost for many reasons, especially when swapping views (are you using a CardLayout for this?). Key Bindings on the other hand can be set to be responsive even if the bound component doesn't have focus but when it is only held within a window that has focus. Tutorial: [Using a CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

**Edit**
I see that you're not using a CardLayout, and I suggest that you use this as it can make your view swapping cleaner and easier.

**Edit 2**
I agree that you don't want to post your entire 2000+ line program here as no one will have the time to read it, but consider condensing your question/problem into a single small class that is compilable and runnable by any and all of us, and demonstrates your problem.  In other words, a [Short, Self Contained, Compilable, Example or SSCCE](http://sscce.org) .

Remember, the code should be compilable and runnable for many of us to be able to understand it fully.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, I read about the CardLayout, but it only hides the panel, and not removes it (right?), and it may cause FPS drop. I can't really make an example code, it's too big for this. Instead, ill just explain it. The KeyListener is the simple public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) and KeyReleased. There are two classes, they are in JPanels that have 2 different KeyListeners. You have to add and remove JPanels in the main class, which is a JFrame. I think i just need a method that adds, and removes KeyListeners. Thank you again! :)

Comment: Also, i rewritten the switching to be better. I made a launcher class for the JPanel: http://pastebin.com/Eyubj06C and, i added a method to the main class like this: http://pastebin.com/GTiWYEt1 and it's called when a button is entered like this: main.singlePlay(sc); where sc = menu. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SimonTamás: I can't tell you much based on this small snips of code, sorry.

Comment: Ok, so now im using cardLayout, the jpanels switch properly, but the keyListner is still screwed up :(. So, for example, i have the Menu and the Singleplayer. They are basically same. Both of them have a TAdapter class, with keyTyped(), keyReleased(), and keyPressed(). These work when opened in a new window, but not in the same window :(. Thanks for advance!

Comment: @SimonTamás: again, what about using key bindings instead?

Comment: key bindings? could you please post a link, or a snip of code for me? :)

Answer (score 2):

Cardlayout actually is screwy while refocusing.

@op, try calling requestFocusInWindow() after the new jpanel was added

Comment: yep, that has been my experience with CardLayout too. Fortunately key bindings can get around this. 1+ for your useful answer.

Comment: I added it, but does nothing :( JPanels are switched, but the KeyListener is gone :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using **`myPanel.requsetFocusInWindow();`**
before using `setVisible(true);`